# Volume form on a Sphere of dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have to construct a volume form on $S^1$. The only things that I know are the definition of differential q-form, and the fact that the vector field $v=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ never vanishes on $S^1$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Use polar coordinates, since, I assume, you know how to get volume form in the real line.

Comment: @studiosus the fact is that i don't have clear how to construct a volume form...the only think that i know is that is never null for every point of my manifold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form is $w=xdy-ydx$. Use $$x=\cos\theta, \qquad y=\sin\theta$$ 
Compute the integral
$$\int_{S^1}w$$